# Function outputs different result when passed through apply in R

Tags: r, apply

I have a function that takes in long format data and checks if each group has unique values. It reports a 1 when the group has no unique values and 0 otherwise. When I pass through a column from a dataframe, it correctly gives the value 1 to indicate that one of the groups has all the same values. However, when I pass the function through apply, I get a different value as before.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

```
check_repeated <- function(df, group_var, value_var) {
  
  # Group the data by the specified variable
  grouped_df <- df %>% 
    group_by({{group_var}})
  
  # Check if all values in the variable are repeated within each group
  all_repeated <- grouped_df %>% 
    summarise(n_distinct = n_distinct({{value_var}})) %>% 
    pull(n_distinct) == 1
  
  return(sum(all_repeated))
}

df <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3),
  value1 = c(2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6),
  value2 = c("w", "w", "w", "r","r","w"),
  value3 = c(2,2,2,2,3,2)
)

 
apply(df[,-1], 2, check_repeated, df=df, group_var=df$group)
check_repeated(df, group, value2)
```

Comment: Not clear why you are applying tidyverse functions in base R.  It may not work.  the group_var in check_repeated expects unquoted column name and not the value (`df$group`)

Comment: If you need it for value columns, `df %>% summarise(across(starts_with('value'), n_distinct), .by = 'group')`

Comment: `apply` is designed for matrices, and will convert a dataframe to a matrix before doing anything.  That will convert your numeric columns to character.

Comment: Also your function is designed to work on a `data.frame`. All the `dplyr` functions expect data frames, not matrices. `apply` is not a good choice because it converts to matrix. Even `lapply` would be a bad choice as it will pass individual columns to your function, not data frame.

Comment: *"has no unique values"* does not seem (to me) to be the same as *"all the same values"*. It would help to reveal what actual values you expect to return for this sample data.

Comment: If all the values are the same, per group, then none are unique. So I could like something to indicate when there is a unique value within the group. The code you and akrun provided, before it got deleted, actually worked. Thank you both for the help!

Comment: A quick rehash of the deleted answer-code might be `df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(across(starts_with('value'), ~ +(n_distinct(.) == 1L)), .by = 'group')`, not entirely sure if that matches your expectations or now. If it's reversed (0-for-1), change `==` to `!=`. If neither, please add expected output to your question. Thanks!

Comment: @akrun, why did you delete your answer? It was so close and (I think) the right way to go.

Comment: This last bit of code doesn't seem to work now. Originally, my desired output was just a tally of the groups that didn't have any unique entries. The code provided previously didn't have that, but the output from it worked for me anyway.

Comment: It isn't clear how you intend to aggregate this to once per group. Is it that _all_ columns must be invariant (only one value present) for a group to be a 1? _Please_ provide actual explicit expected output, as in `data.frame(group=c("A","B"), ret=0:1)` or whatever. I think there may be confusion in what you mean by "not having unique".

Comment: I'm not 100% what you mean. I was looking for a 1 for each group where all the values for that group are the same and 0 otherwise. I should've added, my function is meant to sum all these values, so that if the sum equals the sample size, I'll know that for every group, there are only repeated values. Sorry if this is unclear, I'm in a bit of a rush as I'm on my way out the office.